# Why do some exponents in RSA have the plaintext as a result

Tags: encryption, rsa

The goal is to have a encryption like:

c = m^e mod n

where c = m

I messed up in my conclusion by estimating that e=1 or e=4^x when 4^x < n, the second part is not true and a result of messy written code.

For better understanding:

c= encryptet Text

m= plain Text

n= the procuct of two primes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason for an arbitrary message `m` to have `m^{4^x} = m mod n`

A counterexample;

n=47∗43=2021

5^{4^2} = 1803 mod 2021 , see at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E%7B4%5E2%7D%20mod%202021)

```
import math
for m in range(1,2020):
    for e in (4**x for x in range(1, int(math.log(2021,4))) ):
        if (m**(e) % 2021) == m:
            print (m,e)
```

With this python code you can see the examples for the specific modulus 2021.

As you can see many of the cases happens

```
(423, 4)
(423, 16)
(423, 64)
(423, 256)
```

---

Now, the reason is clear if you remember the RSA definition.

the `e` must have an inverse in phi(n). See live at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+16+mod+phi(2021))

So this choice of `e` is not RSA.

Note since phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1), any even `e` cannot be a public modulus.